# jQuery mmenu - option to have active menu pre-opened

Tags: jquery, mobile, mmenu

Does anybody know if there is an option in [mmenu](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/) to have the current active menu pre-opened? A quick jQuery code snippet should suffice if not.

Otherwise I'll code and post my own snippet later.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the "open" custom event on the menu you want to be opened onDocumentReady.